PuLP: Constrain the number of distinct people that can work on a task
I have a LP/IP problem that I'm trying to solve using PuLP. It is the division of work amongst employees. The thing that I can't figure out is how to limit the engine to only plan 1 employee on an action. In reality the problem has significantly more constraints, but I tried to minimise the problem as much as possible.
Say I have a specific workload:
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "actions": [
        "ActionA",
        "ActionB",
        "ActionC",
        "ActionD",
    ],
    "value": [5, 2, 1, 1],
    "available_work": [8, 4, 12, 24],
}
work = pd.DataFrame(data=data).set_index("actions")




actions
value
available_work




ActionA
5
8


ActionB
2
4


ActionC
1
12


ActionD
1
24



and also a list of people able to work:
data = {
    "ID": [
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05",
    ],
    "time": [7, 7, 6, 5, 5],
}
employees = pd.DataFrame(data=data).set_index("ID")




ID
time




01
7


02
7


03
6


04
5


05
5



I want to maximize the value using the time of the 5 employees:
prob = pulp.LpProblem('PlanningActions', pulp.LpMaximize)
I create a dictionary called vars to contain the referenced variables:
vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts(
    "division",
    (work.index, employees.index),
    lowBound=0
    cat=pulp.LpInteger,
)

I don't want to plan more work on a person than there is available work:
for details in work.itertuples():
    prob += (
        pulp.lpSum([vars[details.Index][m] for m in employees.index])
        <= details.available_work,
        f"Not more than available work {details.Index}",
    )

and I also don't want to plan more work on an employee than it has available time:
for m in employees.index:
    prob += (
        pulp.lpSum([vars[w][m] for w in work.index])
        <= int(employees.loc[m, "time"]),
        f"Not more than available time employee {m}",
    )

This al works properly. However, I can't figure out the constraint to only plan 1 employee on an action. I figured it would look something like this
for action in work.index:
    if action == 'ActionA':
        prob += (
            pulp.lpSum([vars[action][m]>0)
            <= 1,
            f"Not more than one employee for {action}",
    )

But I can't seem to compare the variable (vars) with integer, since I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'LpVariable' and 'int'

You're already using Pandas - but not in a way that particularly helps you. dicts() should be replaced with matrix(), and the += implicit constraint form should be replaced with explicit addConstraint.
The other answer gets about halfway there, but you need to both add continuous variables for hours, and enforce them using big-M constraints:
import pandas as pd
import pulp

actions = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index(name='action', data=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')),
    data={
        'value': (5, 2, 1, 1),
        'max_work': (8, 4, 12, 24),
    }
)

people = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.RangeIndex(name='person', start=1, stop=6),
    data={
        'max_hours': (7, 7, 6, 5, 5),
    },
)

combos = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'assign': pd.DataFrame(
            index=actions.index, columns=people.index,
            data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
                name='assign', indices=(actions.index, people.index),
                cat=pulp.LpBinary,
            ),
        ).stack(),
        'hours': pd.DataFrame(
            index=actions.index, columns=people.index,
            data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
                name='hours', indices=(actions.index, people.index),
                cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0,
            ),
        ).stack(),
    }
)

combos['value_per_hour'] = actions['value'].align(combos)[0]
combos['value'] = combos['hours'] * combos['value_per_hour']
people['hours'] = combos['hours'].groupby('person').sum()
actions['work'] = combos['hours'].groupby('action').sum()

prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='PlanningActions', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
prob.setObjective(pulp.lpSum(combos['value']))

for person, assigns in combos['assign'].groupby('person'):
    # There must be at most one assignment per person
    # Is this needed?
    # prob.addConstraint(
    #     name=f'excl_{person}',
    #     constraint=pulp.lpSum(assigns) <= 1,
    # )
    # Limit hours per person
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'hours_{person}',
        constraint=people.loc[person, 'hours'] <= people.loc[person, 'max_hours'],
    )

for action, assigns in combos['assign'].groupby('action'):
    # There must be at most one assignment per action
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'excl_{action}',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(assigns) <= 1,
    )
    # Limit hours to action
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'hours_{action}',
        constraint=actions.loc[action, 'work'] <= actions.loc[action, 'max_work'],
    )

M = 2*max(
    actions['max_work'].max(),
    people['max_hours'].max(),
)
for (action, person), row in combos.iterrows():
    # Hours must be constrained by assignment
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'assigned_hours_{action}_{person}',
        constraint=row['hours'] <= row['assign']*M,
    )

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

combos = combos.map(pulp.value)
print(combos)
people = people.map(pulp.value)
print(people)
actions = actions.map(pulp.value)
print(actions)

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                56.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

               assign  hours  value_per_hour  value
action person                                      
A      1          0.0    0.0               5    0.0
       2          1.0    7.0               5   35.0
       3          0.0    0.0               5    0.0
       4          0.0    0.0               5    0.0
       5          0.0    0.0               5    0.0
B      1          0.0    0.0               2    0.0
       2          0.0    0.0               2    0.0
       3          0.0    0.0               2    0.0
       4          0.0    0.0               2    0.0
       5          1.0    4.0               2    8.0
C      1          1.0    7.0               1    7.0
       2          0.0    0.0               1    0.0
       3          0.0    0.0               1    0.0
       4          0.0    0.0               1    0.0
       5          0.0    0.0               1    0.0
D      1          0.0    0.0               1    0.0
       2          0.0    0.0               1    0.0
       3          1.0    6.0               1    6.0
       4          0.0    0.0               1    0.0
       5          0.0    0.0               1    0.0
        max_hours  hours
person                  
1               7    7.0
2               7    7.0
3               6    6.0
4               5    0.0
5               5    4.0
        value  max_work  work
action                       
A           5         8   7.0
B           2         4   4.0
C           1        12   7.0
D           1        24   6.0


Your variable vars[w][e] already represents the binary asignment of worker e to action w (following your code notation). If you require that the sum of all vars over an action is less or equals than 1 you guarantee that you 0 or 1 assignements are done per action.
for action in work.index:
    prob += (
        pulp.lpSum([vars[action][emp] for emp in employees.index]) <= 1,
        f"Not more than one employee for {action}",
    )

Or for strict assignment use the == operator.
for action in work.index:
    prob += (
        pulp.lpSum([vars[action][emp] for emp in employees.index]) == 1,
        f"Stictly one employee for {action}",
    )

The issue with your implementation is that in pulp only "==", ">=", "<=" are allowed and not strict inequalities ">", "<", Pulp sense docs (source of the error), and second (once you fix the first inequality error) you are placing a constraint (>0) inside another constraint (sum() <= 1) which make no sense.
Update:
It seems that the real question is how to keep track of the work hours done by the employees. This can be done by creating a continous variable to keep track of the variables worked by every employee and use constraints to bound the var[w][e] binary values.
hours_done_by_employee = pulp.LpVariable.dicts(
    "division",
    employees.index,
    lowBound=0
)

for employees_index in employees.index:
    prob += (
        hours_done_by_employee[employees_index] <= pulp.lpSum(
            [vars[action_index][employees_index]*work.loc[action_index, "available_work"] for action_index in work.index]
        ),
        f"No more hours worked than the work that has been assigned."
    )

for employees_index in employees.index:
    prob += (
        hours_done_by_employee[employees_index] <= employees.loc[employees_index, "time"],
        f"No more hours worked than the max available time for the employee"
    )

prob.setObjective(pulp.lpSum(hours_done_by_employee))


With this constraint, the number of hours per action is set to <=/== 1, however I want someone to be able to work it's full available time (f.e. 7 hours) on one action. With the constraint above all actions are only executed for 1 hour.

These are separate issues. The question was how to get the constraint "to only plan (have) 1 employee on an action". Your variables vars[w][e]={0,1} are binary and represent employees assigned to actions, not hours worked. For that you need to introdude a new continous variable to keep track of the hours worked.

This question is diverging too much from original and at this point has nothing to do with programming but MILP modeling. If the real issue in not yet answered may I suggest you move https://or.stackexchange.com/ which would be the adequate forum for this issue?

vars[w][e] is an integer range Z+ {0, 1, 2, 3, . . .}, so it can take on all possible integers, which are then restricted by the constraints. However, I will be asking this question on or.stackexchange.com, thanks for the effort.
